# Chef recipe - To remove a package when you don't know the exact package name

Tags: chef

I am aware of the [package resources](http://docs.chef.io/#Resources-Package), what I am struggling with is how do I find the exact package name? Since there will different versions of OS in different nodes, how to write a recipe to uninstall a particular package for all?

Like for example NFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the exact package name up to the architecture, version and patch level. You only need to know that package **name** and the underlying package manager will deal with the rest.

Since I only have a CentOS 6 box at hand to play with right now:

```
rpm -qa | grep php           # OR similar:
yum list installed |grep php

php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64
php-devel-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

list every package installed and filter on php. Then display the package info with `yum info`

```
yum info php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 

Installed Packages
Name        : php-pecl-apc
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.1.9
Release     : 2.el6
Size        : 318 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : APC caches and optimizes PHP intermediate code
URL         : http://pecl.php.net/package/APC
License     : PHP
Description : APC is a free, open, and robust framework for caching and optimizing PHP
            : intermediate code.
```

and then to use it in Chef the package name `php-pecl-apc` is sufficient.

Package names are for a large part fairly consistent between different releases.

So the short of it is that you'll need to spend some time learning the relevant package manager, because remove packages may not be without impact to other installed packages that require it as a dependancy.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, thank you. How can I delete a package with all its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to use a case statement to set the package name depending on the platform or platform family.  From https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html

```
package 'Install Apache' do
  case node[:platform]
  when 'redhat', 'centos'
    package 'httpd'
  when 'ubuntu', 'debian'
   package 'apache2'
 end
end
```